# Encrypt in JavaSscript with NaCl, Decrypt With PHP libsodium using KeyPair

Tags: javascript, php, security, encryption, libsodium

i want to use [NaCl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tweetnacl) library in the client side and [libsodium](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium_compat) in php to encrypt/decrypt messages between the client and the server using keypair(public,private).

When i encrypt with libsodium and decrypt with NaCl everything works, But when i try to encrypt with NaCl and decrypt with libsodium i get no result.

**Encrypting with NaCl in the client side**

```
var message = "Sample Message";
var bytes = nacl.util.decodeUTF8(message);

var client_public = nacl.util.hex2bytearray('35e9f8477b60f61747722698d98791c4e0818ff75da3943a30e13dc0a457d402');
var client_private = nacl.util.hex2bytearray('6382cd5ef713375b6fe3835a763c72dfdc7ddcade7b8bcb9640065582708ef2c');
var server_public = nacl.util.hex2bytearray('1f348bac3b60d3076fc1a32d4e205df67356a9ef16d4b3f391c0e4817f3b987f');

var sharedkey = nacl.box.before(server_public, client_private);
var nonce = nacl.util.hex2bytearray('c031122a5f57e253686d9f6082d1061a1546e5567290c7f0'); // 24 bytes

var cipher = nacl.box.after(bytes, nonce, sharedkey );
var cihper_with_nonce = nacl.util.bytearray2hex(nonce) + bytearray2hex(cipher); // will be sent to the server
//c031122a5f57e253686d9f6082d1061a1546e5567290c7f0b2c05c9fb1483fe9b1bd2d4ae261832a54569748dd7925511b3d236e23e8
```

```
nacl.util.hex2bytearray = hexString => new Uint8Array(hexString.match(/.{1,2}/g).map(byte => parseInt(byte, 16)));
nacl.util.bytearray2hex = bytes => bytes.reduce((str, byte) => str + byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'), '');
nacl.util.decodeUTF8=function(e){;var n,r=unescape(encodeURIComponent(e)),t=new Uint8Array(r.length);for(n=0;n<r.length;n++)t[n]=r.charCodeAt(n);return t}
```

**Decrypting with libsodium in PHP**

```
$cihper_with_nonce = 'c031122a5f57e253686d9f6082d1061a1546e5567290c7f0b2c05c9fb1483fe9b1bd2d4ae261832a54569748dd7925511b3d236e23e8';// received from the client
$server_public = hex2bin('1f348bac3b60d3076fc1a32d4e205df67356a9ef16d4b3f391c0e4817f3b987f');// generated with libsodium
$server_private = hex2bin('cea48d3c14bc9ad26bf3f62932db5d7336b8212866c14dec64670f295ec89d5d');// generated with libsodium
$client_public = hex2bin('35e9f8477b60f61747722698d98791c4e0818ff75da3943a30e13dc0a457d402');// generated with NaCl

$sharedkey = sodium_crypto_box_keypair_from_secretkey_and_publickey($server_private, $client_public );

$nonce = hex2bin(substr($cihper_with_nonce, 0, 48));//24 bytes
$cihper = hex2bin(substr($cihper_with_nonce, 48));

$message = sodium_crypto_box_open($cihper , $nonce, $sharedkey );
var_dump($message);// bool(false)
```

**Am i using the Library the Wrong way or there is something i am doing it wrong?** 
Because when i encrypt with php and decrypt with NaCl everything works and i did the same way in reverse for the Decryption.
all the bytes(hex) used are generated with the same library.
NaCl Source [nacl](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/tweetnacl) [util](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/tweetnacl-util) 
libsodium Source [libsodium](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium_compat)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, [here](https://onecompiler.com/php/3vy2sefv3). When determining `$sharedkey` an undefined variable is used, `$private` instead of `$server_private`, maybe this is the reason for the problem.

Comment: "i get no result.". Not a clear error description.

Comment: there is no problem in the code, i was using a wrong library without knowing, closed.